# Simple addition in php

Tags: php

While adding with mysql result I am not able to get the total.

```
<?php

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 ");

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
    echo "{{$row['id']}+1}";
}

?>
```

Here I am getting the result as "27+1".
But I want "28". Please point out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they will be removed from PHP in future versions and your code will stop working then. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP thinks that you are trying to concatenate the strings, so I suggest that you explicitly add two numbers and echo the result:

```
<?php
    //execute the SQL query and return records
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 ");
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
        $incremented = $row['id'] + 1;
        echo $incremented;
    }

?>
```

Also, not related directly to your question, I recommend you to stop using `mysql_query` and similar functions since they are deprecated, and in PHP 7 it is removed. Try using PDO or mysqli extensions instead.

Comment: Why use an additional variable? And why not use the `increment operator`? So simply this inside the loop: `echo ++$row['id'];`

Comment: Nice. It is working fine. I understand. Thanks for early reply.

Comment: Yes, I should use increment operator. That is better.

Comment: Doesn't it change the value of the element itself? What if there is a need to use it after that?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement will be full-fill using pre-increment operator :

```
<?php
    //execute the SQL query and return records
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 ");
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
        echo ++$row['id'];
    }
?>
```

See [Result](https://eval.in/488969)

Comment: I disagree. This will change the value of the variable and we can't be sure that this is OK. We only need to print the incremented result, why change the value itself?

Answer (score 0):

well you can directly get it done via query too (if you want to keep adding the ids)

```
 SELECT count(id) as idCount FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

If you want to know the total count

```
 SELECT count(*) as idCount FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

and on application layer

```
 echo $row['id']+1;
```

Will do the job.

Answer (score -1):

why cant you sort out this in query itself, try this..

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT (id+1) as id, col2 FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 ");
```